# How load windows music library in media elenent on UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, media

How load windows music library in media elenent on UWP? I make music player on media element(not media player element). I have list music files i can load this list in media player element and cant load this list in media element. Code for create music list load later.
Code generate music list:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {


        StorageFolder musicLib = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
        //file massive
        var files = await musicLib.GetFilesAsync();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var musicProperties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
            var artist = musicProperties.Artist;
            if (artist == "")
                artist = "UnKnown";
            var album = musicProperties.Album;
            if (album == "")
                album = "Unknown";

            SongList.Add((new Song { SongName = file.DisplayName, Artist = artist, Album = album, Path = file.Path }));
            MediaPlaybackItem Item = new MediaPlaybackItem(MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file));
            mplPlaybackList.Items.Add(Item);
        }

        PopulateAlbumAndArtistLists();

        PlayerManager.lvSongsList.ItemsSource = SongList;
        //Load list to mediaplayer element
        meMyPlayer.Source = mplPlaybackList;
    }
```

Comment: Please show us the code of what you've already tried and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: If I replace the mediaplayerelement with a media element, then swears at meMyPlayer.Source = mplPlaybackList;

Answer (score 0):

> Can't load this list in media element.

When you set the MediaPlaybackList, pass it to the playback source of MediaElement instead of Source.

.xaml:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" AutoPlay="True"></MediaElement>
```

.cs:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    _mediaPlaybackList = new MediaPlaybackList();
    SongList = new ObservableCollection<Song>();
    StorageFolder musicLib = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
    //file massive
    var files = await musicLib.GetFilesAsync();
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var musicProperties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
        var artist = musicProperties.Artist;
        if (artist == "")
            artist = "UnKnown";
        var album = musicProperties.Album;
        if (album == "")
            album = "Unknown";

        SongList.Add((new Song { SongName = file.DisplayName, Artist = artist, Album = album, Path = file.Path }));
        MediaPlaybackItem Item = new MediaPlaybackItem(MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file));
        _mediaPlaybackList.Items.Add(Item);
    }


    mediaElement.SetPlaybackSource(_mediaPlaybackList);
    }
```

Comment: Ok then how do i fix this part of the code: 
`private void lvSongsList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MediaPlaybackList mpl2 = (MediaPlaybackList)PlayerManager.meMyPlayer.Source;
            if (lvSongsList.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                mpl2.MoveTo((uint)lvSongsList.SelectedIndex);
                PlayerManager.meMyPlayer.MediaPlayer.Play();
            }
        }`

Comment: This code select song in ListView. Error in this string: ` MediaPlaybackList mpl2 = (MediaPlaybackList)PlayerManager.meMyPlayer.Source;` And after your corrections player cant swith songs.

Comment: You can go the other way and make MediaPlayerElement work when minimizing the application if it is easier

Comment: MediaElement is no longer updated. It is recommended to use MediaPlayerElement after 1607. All future updates will be applied to MediaPlayerElement. So currently, it's better to use MediaPlayerElement instead of MediaElement.

Comment: MediaPlayerElement does not work in the background, if you have a working instruction I would be grateful.

Comment: If you want to play media in the background, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio).